# Calculating the complexity parameter in Rpart

Tags: r, rpart

I am stuck on trying to reproduce the following output table in RPart:

```
          CP    nsplit   rel error    xerror      xstd
  1 0.10493827      0   1.0000000 1.0000000 0.1080241  
  2 0.05555556      3   0.6851852 1.0370370 0.1088041  
  3 0.02777778      4   0.6296296 0.9444444 0.1066785  
  4 0.01851852      6   0.5740741 0.9444444 0.1066785  
  5 0.01000000      7   0.5555556 0.9814815 0.1075992
```

I can repoduce the nsplit and rel error numbers, but I don't see how to arrive at the CP values.  I believe that CP is the change in error divided by the change in the number of leaves, but I cannot reproduce the values shown here.

The R code I am running is:

```
   load(file='D:/Rdata/stagec.rda')
   progstat <- factor(stagec$pgstat, levels = 0:1, labels = c("No", "Prog"))
   cfit <- rpart(progstat ~ age + eet + g2 + grade + gleason + ploidy,
              data = stagec, method = 'class')
   printcp(cfit)
```

The data file stagec.rda  is available in Github at https://github.com/bethatkinson/rpart/tree/master/data.

Thanks for any insight into this.

Answer (score 0):

For me works perfectly

```
> options(digits=9)
> cfit <- rpart(progstat ~ age + eet + g2 + grade + gleason + ploidy,
+               data = stagec, method = 'class')
> 
> printcp(cfit)

Classification tree:
rpart(formula = progstat ~ age + eet + g2 + grade + gleason + 
    ploidy, data = stagec, method = "class")

Variables actually used in tree construction:
[1] age    g2     grade  ploidy

Root node error: 54/146 = 0.369863

n= 146 

          CP nsplit rel error    xerror      xstd
1 0.10493827      0 1.0000000 1.0000000 0.1080241
2 0.05555556      3 0.6851852 1.0370370 0.1088041
3 0.02777778      4 0.6296296 0.9814815 0.1075992
4 0.01851852      6 0.5740741 0.9074074 0.1056608
5 0.01000000      7 0.5555556 0.9629630 0.1071508
>
```

You can see I just added the options to get more digits in the decimal part.

I use this R version: `R version 3.6.3 (2020-02-29)`

Comment: Thanks. I did not realize that the change in CP was based on adjacent values. I erroneously thought that the comparison was always with the model with the most splits.